# Pre-Build Target not running

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I created an MSBuild target to restore NPM packages in my ASP.NET Core app. I modeled it after Microsoft's own project template target for Node.js projects, though my project is not Node.js it only uses NPM packages for TypeScript defs.

When my Azure DevOps pipeline builds it does not run my target unless I explicitly force it to with *-t:RestoreNode*. Why does my target trigger in Visual Studio but not in DevOps? Here is my target:

```
<Target Name="RestoreNode" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
  <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
    <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
  </Exec>
  <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
  <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
  <Exec Command="npm install" />
</Target>
```

Here is the pipeline:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  runtimeConfiguration: 'win-x64'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '-t:RestoreNode --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --runtime $(runtimeConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) --runtime $(runtimeConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: How is going with this case? Any good new?

Comment: I think I'm just going to give up... I tried several different combinations of "projects" variables and none of them worked.

Comment: I think I found a hint. Without manually specifying the targets on the command line the RestoreNode target is running after Build even though the target is configured with BeforeTargets="Build" and I tried BeforeTargets="Build;Publish".

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce above scenario. 
After add `projects: '**/*.csproj'` to your first `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task. The `RestoreNode` target was executed correctly on my test project.

`- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --runtime $(runtimeConfiguration)'`

I also tried below task `VSBuild@1`. it was working as expected too. You can have a try with this task.

`- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**/*.sln'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'`

Below I posted the build log from my pipeline:

```
[command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build d:\a\1\s\MsBuildTarget\MsBuildTarget\MsBuildTarget.csproj --configuration Release --runtime win-x64

Welcome to .NET Core 3.0!
---------------------
SDK Version: 3.0.100
...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.3.0+0f4c62fea for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 7.13 sec for d:\a\1\s\MsBuildTarget\MsBuildTarget\MsBuildTarget.csproj.
  MsBuildTarget -> d:\a\1\s\MsBuildTarget\MsBuildTarget\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\win-x64\MsBuildTarget.dll
  v10.16.3
  Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes...
  npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\a\1\s\MsBuildTarget\MsBuildTarget\package.json'
  npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\a\1\s\MsBuildTarget\MsBuildTarget\package.json'
  npm WARN MsBuildTarget No description
  npm WARN MsBuildTarget No repository field.
  npm WARN MsBuildTarget No README data
  npm WARN MsBuildTarget No license field.
```

Comment: I added "projects" to the build task:

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --runtime 
    $(runtimeConfiguration)'

I got the same error. The libman packages restore, as usual, but the NPM target doesn't run. I also tried VSBuild but I wasn't able to pass "--runtime" to MSBuild. As far as I can tell "runtime" has to be passed to the .NET Core task. The platform is always "Any CPU".

Comment: I noticed the projects values you typed is "*/.csproj". the value of projects property shoudl be`"**/*.csproj"`, which searches for all projects(csproj) in all subdirectories.  If the project cannot be found by dotnet build task, then the target wouldnot be able to executed. You can go to the build log to check if the project that you defined the "NPM target " is searched and added to dotnet build command. As for vsbuild task, argument "platform" gets the default platform if you donot specify a variable to override it.